# How to add a data in a column if that data doesnt remain in a table for a specific foreign key in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a table named `category` where I have 2 columns `cat_id` and `cat_name`

table looks like this

```
cat_id   cat_name
1         Science
2         Arts
```

I have another table called `item`, where `cat_id` of `category` table is foreign key and the table looks like

```
item_id       item_name    cat_id
1              math          1
2              literature    2
3              physics       1
```

now I want to write a query like that if I insert math again in `Science` then it wont insert but if I want to insert math in `Arts` then it will successfully insert. Please keep in mind that I only have the `item_name` and `cat_name` in my hand and I want to add `item_name` and the `cat_id` of that `cat_name` in item table.

So far I did is like this

```
insert into item (item_name,cat_id) select 'abdul',category.cat_id from category where NOT EXISTS (select * from item WHERE category.cat_id = item.foreign_id)
```

but this givs me awkward result, can anyone help?

Comment: so is it MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: SQLite or MYSQL, if you can help with any thing should clear me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically not realising that this is just a [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) issue. This becomes evident when you try to insert "math" twice in the same table. This is a many-to-many and not a one-to-many relationship. Rule of thumb: *Many-to-many relationships always generate a table*.

The appropriate table structure would look like this (sample data included):

**Categories**: (cat_id)

```
cat_id   cat_name
1         Science
2         Arts
```

**Items**: (item_id)

```
item_id       item_name
1              math
2              literature
3              physics
```

**Categories_Items** (cat_id, item_id)

```
cat_id       item_id
1              1
1              3
2              2
```

In round brackets you'll see the primary keys. Bear in mind that the last table has a compound PK. That will allow you not to repeat math for the same category.